# How to make the buttons of a horizontal menu functional?

Tags: javascript, php, html

In the code given below, I want to make the buttons functional. Like when I click them they should do a specific task! For example : When they click 'home' the script should go to another html file and when they click about they should go to another html file, and the crucial one is when they click on the System -> Shutdown/Reboot/KillSwitch it should execute specific commands in the linux system it is running on. Since it was kind of difficult for me to post the code here, please go to this link to see the code,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
    ul{
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    ul li{
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 21px;
    }
    ul li a{
        display: block;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        color: #333;
        background: #f2f2f2;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    ul li a:hover{
        color: #fff;
        background: #939393;
    }
    ul li ul{
        display: none;
    }
    ul li:hover ul{
        display: block; /* display the dropdown */
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">System &#9662;</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Shutdown</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reboot</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Killswitch</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Paste the code also in SO so we don't have to go to pastebin. SO also supports snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using **CGI** scripts.

- First make sure you have correctly setup your webserver to run CGI scripts.
- Then do `visudo` and give permission to the user the webserver is running to run the sudo shutdown command without asking for password. More info you can find here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password. In my system I added the following line to give permission to the www-data user which is the user my Apache runs:

  www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown

And here are the two CGI scripts that you need to put to your cgi-bin folder and can be called from the buttons of your webpage with just simple HTML links.

**restart.cgi**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html><head><title>Restarting"
echo "</title></head><body>"
echo "<h1>Restarting...</h1>"
echo ""
echo "</body></html>"
sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now
```

**shutdown.cgi**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html><head><title>Shutting down"
echo "</title></head><body>"
echo "<h1>Shutting down...</h1>"
echo ""
echo "</body></html>"
sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript running in a browser is sandboxed for a good reason, imagine every site could shoutdown your computer via javascript.
Format your computer when you click a button labeled 'Leave that page'.

However you are only sandboxed in the browser so you can move to another html page with

```
window.location.href = 'http://newpage/...';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is for a simple GUI project for my raspberry pi, this is not a public website* and moreover I got the Home and About button to work.. but the System -> Shutdown/reboot should run a specific linux command on click is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write some code to wrap around a typical web browser which interprets specifically for your website and will reboot the system when it is given the proper circumstance. As @overflowed mentions, no generic browser the common person uses would allow this.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to shutdown.reboot,kill the server that is hosting your site you could go with php but keep in mind that web scripts on your server are run by httpd/apache user or maybe a special user you have assigned. So in order to achieve what you want you could do a root crontab on your server which will take a minute to reboot the server.

the plan is like this: with php create a file in the web directory of your server then the crontab runs a script which checks if the file exists ... if exists the delete it and reboot server... else if it doesnt exists do nothing ... ofcourse this path is not advisible and if you do it make sure you log everything good
i give you an example
root crontab content:

`* * * * * /usr/local/sbin/check.sh`

the content of check.sh:

```
 #!/bin/bash
if [ -f /var/www/html/restart.myserver ]; then
  rm -f /var/www/html/restart.myserver
  /sbin/shutdown -r now 
fi
```

and the php file lets say restart.php which will be linked to your anchor element

```
    <?php fh = fopen("/var/www/html/restart.myserver",'w');
    fwrite($fh,"Reboot now\n");
    fclose($fh);
    ?>
```